# PlexCard Visa : Would it be legal all around the world?

Tags: currencies, legal, transaction-verification

Recently, Plexcoin is to come up in the market with very promising future. Directly, citing from their website, the features include

**In comparison to Bitcoin (45 minutes), the transactions (deposit, withdrawal, purchase, sale, transfer) of PlexCoin are confirmed faster (30 seconds) and they have increased storage efficiency.**

and

**With PlexCoin, you will be able to undertake regular transactions and spend money with your PlexCard VISA© anywhere around the world. You will also have the option to send or receive funds from anyone, in a totally private way.**

Will the VISA card be legally accepted around the world ?

and

How can they achieve(claim) to have such fast transaction confirmation time ?

Comment: I would note that there's no indication that Plexcoin has reached any agreement with VISA. It's easy to photoshop your logo on top of a VISA card. PayCoin pulled the exact same scam.

Answer (score 1):

VISA and MasterCard cards are issued by banks all over the world, that have a valid license. It's not the first time we see **cryptocurrency based VISA card**. Those cards can be used in every shop (online or physical) that accepts VISA cards.

If this **PlexCard VISA** card is issued by a bank that has a valid license to issue VISA cards, then the card will be legally accepted wherever VISA cards are accepted.

As for the second question (fast transaction confirmation time), I don't know about PlexCoin but there are other coins with near instant confirmation times, that are using techniques like faster block time and/or MasterNodes.